# Can't resolve '../../theme.config'

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a project structure like this:

```
├── public
│   └── index.html
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── App.js
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── actions
│   │   ├── api
│   │   ├── constants
│   │   ├── reducers
│   │   ├── sagas
│   │   ├── selects
│   │   ├── store
│   │   └── utils
│   ├── components
│   ├── containers
│   ├── index.js
│   └── styles
│       ├── site
│       ├── style.less
│       ├── theme.config
│       ├── theme.less
│       └── themes
├── webpack.config.js
```

in webpack i have alias:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        '../../theme.config$': path.join(__dirname, '/styles/theme.config')
    }
}
```

but alias won't work:

`@import (multiple) '../../theme.config';
^
Can't resolve '../../theme.config'`

I don't know what i do wrong. 
Maybe I am doing the wrong config for aliases?

Comment: Why don't call the file theme.config.js ? So Webpack standard config will fit with no effort..

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini https://medium.com/@marekurbanowicz/how-to-customize-fomantic-ui-with-less-and-webpack-applicable-to-semantic-ui-too-fbf98a74506c

Answer (score 1):

Your webpack configuration is outside `src`, thus your alias is incorrect:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        '../../theme.config$': path.join(__dirname, 'src/styles/theme.config')
    }
}
```